# How add new localization for achivment or lederboard items via Play Games Services Publishing API

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

When I add new localization (which not manually added for the game) in the requesting JSON (https://developers.google.com/games/services/publishing/api/achievementConfigurations) for updating achievements or leaderboards the server return following error:

```js
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "UnsupportedLocale",
    "message": "The locale bg in the name field is not supported by the application."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The locale bg in the name field is not supported by the application."
 }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Does the locale bg stand for `Java Locale “Bulgarian” (bg)`? Have you tried others locale?

Answer (score 1):

I believe in order for the API to accept translations, the language needs to be added to the Game definition.  If you go to your Game, then the Game Details tab, click "Add Translations" and add Bulgarian.

Once it is added there, you can use the API to upload the values.